# Python networkx DFS or BFS missing?

Tags: python, networkx

I am interested in finding a path (not necessarily shortest) in a short amount of time. Dijsktra and AStar in networkx is taking too long.

Why is there no DFS or BFS in networkx?

I plan to write my own DFS and BFS search (I am leaning more towards BFS because my graph is pretty deep). Is there anything that I can use in networkx's lib to speed me up?

Answer (score 4):

The [Traversal](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.traversal.html) module has multiple depth-first-search variations. Breadth-first-search [is implemented](http://groups.google.com/group/networkx-discuss/browse_thread/thread/93905139065cb578) in the connected components functions, also in that module. Either use that, or if you need custom behaviour, re-implement your own using that as the example.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a depth-first search and breadth-first search [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.traversal.html)

These are modified from Eppstein's code at www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS
which is also a good place to look for Python graph algorithms.